# Geckodriver in WSL stuck in readyState of 'interactive'

Tags: windows-subsystem-for-linux, geckodriver

I've recently switched computers and I have a script to scrape a site that I'm trying to port over, but it's not working. I'm running `Mozilla Firefox 93.0`, `geckodriver 0.30.0 (d372710b98a6 2021-09-16 10:29 +0300)` with `Python 3.8.10` on Windows Subsystem for Linux

geckodriver.log is the following:

```
1635724994219   geckodriver INFO    Listening on 127.0.0.1:34993
1635724994224   mozrunner::runner   INFO    Running command: "/usr/bin/firefox" "--marionette" "--headless" "--remote-debugging-port" "45483" "-no-remote" "-profile" "/tmp/rust_mozprofileKcEU8P"
*** You are running in headless mode.
1635724994420   Marionette  INFO    Marionette enabled
[GFX1-]: RenderCompositorSWGL failed mapping default framebuffer, no dt
console.warn: SearchSettings: "get: No settings file exists, new profile?" (new NotFoundError("Could not open the file at /tmp/rust_mozprofileKcEU8P/search.json.mozlz4", (void 0)))
DevTools listening on ws://localhost:45483/devtools/browser/ef680f3f-d655-4d3d-86be-7287f5731e16
1635724995327   Marionette  INFO    Listening on port 38833
JavaScript error: resource://services-settings/Attachments.jsm, line 391: TypeError: / is not a valid URL.
1635724995445   RemoteAgent WARN    TLS certificate errors will be ignored for this session
1635724995448   RemoteAgent INFO    Proxy settings initialised: {"proxyType":"manual","httpProxy":"127.0.0.1:46485","sslProxy":"127.0.0.1:46485"}
1635724996122   Marionette  WARN    Ignoring event 'pageshow' because document has an invalid readyState of 'interactive'.
1635725002780   Marionette  WARN    Ignoring event 'pageshow' because document has an invalid readyState of 'interactive'.
[GFX1-]: Receive IPC close with reason=AbnormalShutdown
Exiting due to channel error.
Exiting due to channel error.
Exiting due to channel error.
```

while the program is repeatedly throwing the following error up on the command line.

```
refresh_site() 482 https://www.xkcd.com/
Message: Reached error page: about:neterror?e=nssFailure2&u=https%3A//www.xkcd.com/&c=UTF-8&d=The%20connection%20to%20the%20server%20was%20reset%20while%20the%20page%20was%20loading.
Stacktrace:
WebDriverError@chrome://remote/content/shared/webdriver/Errors.jsm:181:5
UnknownError@chrome://remote/content/shared/webdriver/Errors.jsm:488:5
checkReadyState@chrome://remote/content/marionette/navigate.js:64:24
onNavigation@chrome://remote/content/marionette/navigate.js:312:39
emit@resource://gre/modules/EventEmitter.jsm:160:20
receiveMessage@chrome://remote/content/marionette/actors/MarionetteEventsParent.jsm:42:25
```

I'm familiar with a fair amount of geckodriver errors from previous experience and have usually been able to fix them by reinstalling firefox and geckodriver with matching versions, but this is a new one for me and I don't know what I should do to proceed. Thoughts?

Edit:

For the record, I can initialize the webdriver without error, but when I uncomment out the lin `self.driver.get(self.user_site)` that resuts in an error being thrown every time.

Edit 2:

I suspect it has something to do with the commands to firefox, since on the computer where it works, the log show that it's sending the command as `"/usr/bin/firefox" "--marionette" "--headless" "-foreground" "-no-remote" "-profile" "/tmp/rust_mozprofiledAb1T0"` which is different from what my new computer is doing, but I don't know enough Selenium to fix that off the top of my head.

Edit 3:

I think this is a security certificate issue. I ran the following as a python script and it worked fine.

```
from selenium import webdriver
 
driver = webdriver.Firefox()
driver.get("https://dev.to")
 
driver.find_element_by_id("nav-search").send_keys("Selenium")
```

It still works when I swap in the url that I actually care for, but I get security errors when trying to open in it non-headless mode with my production code.

Edit4:

This code replicates the issue and shows that it can be fixed by changing seleniumwire to selenium

```
from seleniumwire import webdriver

class Foo:

    def __init__(self):
        self.web_options = webdriver.FirefoxOptions()
        self.driver = webdriver.Firefox(options=self.web_options)
    
    def bar(self):
        self.driver.get("https://xkcd.com")
        print(self.driver.current_url)

Foo().bar()
```

The actual error that's stopping seleniumwire is a `AttributeError: module 'lib' has no attribute 'SSL_CTX_get0_param'` error, which is caused by https://pypi.org/project/cryptography/#history being installed as version 2.8 which is two years out of date. This seems like the ultimate answer which I am working on now.

Comment: I think something like https://improveandrepeat.com/2020/05/how-to-fix-your-connection-is-not-secure-in-firefox-and-selenium/ would be the answer, but my first few attempts didn't really help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out my `cryptography` package was out-of-date. I ran `pip install pyopenssl` which fixed the issue.